# What type of event is trigger when user select a file with correct extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, file-upload

I am writing some scripts to capture certain error strings after user upload an excel file. The problem I am having now is in the UI there is a element to click which pop up a native file select window that is OS dependent, after user choose the correct file with ".xlsx" extension then in the UI will have two buttons created: 1. Upload, 2 Remove. After user press the 'Upload' button, the uploade .xlsx file will be validated and then error message will be generated accordingly.

As we are using selenium, that has to upload a file using an input web element which is hidden. I use javascript to make it visible and upload the excel file use that element. Below is how code looks like:

```
    File fileToUpload = new File(
        "testData/SSP/Page/guidedbuying/S4SupplierManagementAdministrationPage/LandingPages.xlsx");
    setElementVisible("landingPageExcelInput");
    WebElement e = findElement(AwBy.xpath(
        "//input[@id='landingPageExcelInput']"));
    selectFileForUpload(e, fileToUpload);
```

But when I do that, the above mentioned two UI buttons (Upload, Remove) will not present, so there is no way for automation code to trigger the validation of the excel file.

Could someone give me some idea, what type of events is triggered when user upload the file with correct file type so that I can use javascript to do the same.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Franker as the code is not using <input> element, so there is on event listener on it, it is not even clickable after I set it to visible, that input element is invisible and not used.

Comment: Which browser/driver/version are you using and have you tried with a different one?

Comment: Could you add the HTML related to the dialog from the screenshot?

Comment: @Florent B, I have upload HTML source, I am using firefox 47.0 with selenium 2. Thanks.

Comment: You've uploaded a screenshot, not the HTML. The relevant part (Browse button)  is missing. Note that your second screenshot indicates that you tried to use the <input> element for the upload but your first comment indicates that there's no  <input> element. So which is it?

Comment: oh, sorry I mean the developer of the webpage are not using <input> element to trigger the excel validation, so when I tried to use that to upload file it doesn't trigger the 'upload' button to load. I cannot copy the HTML source, let me try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is a bad idea to trigger events on the page using Javascript. When you do this, things like this happen because you aren't interacting with the page the way it was designed... as a user would. My suggestion is to interact with the page as a user would. If a user has to click a button to make a control visible, then click that button. Once you do that, this problem will likely be solved.

Comment: Hi JeffC, I understand your point but I have to automate this, we have 25 languages, need to automate this work flow so that we can check if all error validation messages are translated correctly. If click manually we need to repeat this 25 times and have to do screenshot manually. This is the reason i need to automate this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not saying don't automate it. I'm saying don't use Javascript to unhide the INPUT. Script the scenario like a user would interact with the page and you likely won't have these issues.

Comment: You are asking what events do you need to watch for and my point is that the UI will trigger all the correct events for you if you don't shortcut the UI using javascript, etc.

Comment: Hi JeffC, sorry I didn't understand your meaning correctly. I see, I need to do the same as a normal user would do in the automation code, then this problem could possibly be solved, I will try this and get back to you. Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of the HTML, clicking on "Choose file" initiates the listeners and forwards the click to the hidden input which in turns displays the OS file dialog.

So the issue here is probably not with the emitted events, but with whether or not the page is listening to them.

My guess is that the page is not listening to the events when you simply set the file on the input. You probably need to click on the "Choose file" first, but it will display the OS file dialog which can't be handled with Selenium.

One way to handle this situation is to override the click on the `<input>` to avoid the dialog, to perform the click and to set the file with sendKeys:

```
// disable the OS dialog triggered via code on an `<input>` file
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "HTMLInputElement.prototype.click = function() { " +
    "  if(this.type !== 'file')                      " +
    "     HTMLElement.prototype.click.call(this);    " +
    "};                                              " );

// initiate the upload
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[translate='adminPage_CHOOSE_FILE']"))
      .click();

// assign a file to the `<input>`
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=file]"))
      .sendKeys(File("full file path").getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Hi I tried this, the two UI elements are still not present.

Comment: I think it is more complicated than I expected, manually click that admin_CHOOSE_FILE button, pop up the OS dependent file selector window, after select the file, it triggers file extension validation first, if file not end with .xslx then it will display error message only without Upload File button, only when i manually select file with correct extension, it will trigger the loading with the Upload button on the UI.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, It's hard to say why you are not getting the expect result. Your best chance to figure that out is to debug the events in the page to see what's going on. The driver emits the change event on the `<input>`, so it should be handled by the extension validation if it's listening to it.